# La expresión es constante o no, según el contexto ¿por qué?

Tags: c++

Tengo unas plantillas que me transforman un literal de texto en un número:

```
template <auto SIZE, std::size_t ... I>
auto constexpr number(const char (&definition)[SIZE], std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I ...> )
{
    return (definition[I] + ...);
}

template <auto SIZE>
auto constexpr number(const char (&definition)[SIZE])
{
    return number(definition, std::make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, SIZE - 1>{});
}
```

La transformación se hace en tiempo de compilación, ya que puedo usar el retorno de la función en contextos en que se exige una constante:

```
switch (x)
{
    case number("123"):
        std::cout << 150;
        break;
    case number("456"):
        std::cout << 159;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << 0;
        break;
}
```

Quiero que falle la compilación si se le pasa a la función una cadena que no contenga números, pensé en usar `static_assert`:

```
template <auto SIZE, std::size_t ... I>
auto constexpr number(const char (&definition)[SIZE], std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I ...> )
{
    static_assert(((definition[I] >= '0' && definition[I] <= '9') && ...), "No es un numero");
    return (definition[I] + ...);
}
```

Pero en ese contexto, `definition[I]` no es una expresión constante:

> ```
> error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
> static_assert(((definition[I] >= '0' && definition[I] <= '9') && ...), "No es un numero");
>                ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

¿Por qué en algunos lugares es expresión constante y en otros no?

Answer (score 2):

`static_assert` no se puede usar aquí porque `constexpr` **no obliga** a que la función deba ser evaluada **siempre** en tiempo de compilación. Lo que hace `constexpr` es forzar al compilador a evaluar la función en tiempo de compilación **siempre que sea posible**.

Pero claro, `static_assert`, pese a que lo incluyes dentro de la función, no es dependiente de los usos que vaya a tener la función. Es facil ver que si haces una llamada a `number` pasando variables `static_assert` no va a ser capaz de evaluar nada.

Así pues lo único que sabe `static_assert` es que le estás pasando algo que puede acabar siendo una variable y lo único que puede hacer al respecto es detener la compilación.

Para que funcione lo que pretendes, el compilador tendría que apuntarse que esa función solo puede ser utilizada en tiempo de compilación... pero no hay palabra reservada que habilite esa limitación, luego `static_assert` se encuentra con algo que puede no ser evaluado en tiempo de compilación.

La alternativa es lanzar excepciones... suena un poco raro, lo se, pero si a las excepciones le añadimos la magia oscura del condicional ternario conseguimos algo tal que:

```
template <auto SIZE, std::size_t ... I>
auto constexpr number(const char (&definition)[SIZE], std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I ...> )
{ 
    return ((definition[I] >= '0' && definition[I] <= '9' ) && ... ) ? (definition[I] + ...) :  throw std::runtime_error("No es un numero");
}
```

Ahora, siempre que la función sea evaluable en tiempo de compilación, se producirá un error en tiempo de compilación cuando se introduzca un caracter que no sea numérico, mientras que cuando la función no sea evaluable obtendremos una bonita excepción en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Pero el problema (y la duda) es que el compilador **sabe** que la expresión es evaluable en tiempo de compilación, porque de hecho la evalúa en tiempo de compilación ¿Por qué en un contexto sabe que una expresión es `constexpr` y en otro contexto se olvida de lo que sabe?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Son cosas diferentes aunque la intuición nos diga que son iguales. los requisitos de `static_cast` no tienen apartados especiales para cuando se encuentra en funciones `constexpr`, luego `static_cast` ve una variable donde tu ves una constante. Sin embargo sí que podrías evaluar en una `static_assert` el resultado de una función `constexpr` porque ahí `static_cast` **sí que ve** una constante.